# Style parent when child is hovered over and clicked

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

I'm using a tab navigation script that assigns a class to the selected tab and a tab that's hovered over. For my particular layout I require the tab function to work on a span within each li.

```
<li class="tabs tab1"><span>Tab one</span></li>
```

The tab script assigns a class to the span when it's clicked

```
<li class="tabs"><span class="selected">Tab one</span></li>
```

And when it's hovered over

```
<li class="tabs"><span class="hover">Tab one</span></li>
<li class="tabs"><span class="selected hover">Tab one</span></li>
```

I need to change the background of the parent `li` when a `span` is clicked or hovered over. 
Ideally, this should be done **without changes to the moo_tabcontrol.js** script, and also **without jQuery**. I would be very grateful for any help here as I'm rather illiterate when if comes to Javascript. Many thanks.

Here is the whole setup: http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/3a69W/6/

I thought that maybe the parent could also be assigned 'selected' or 'hover' as a class (CSS for this scenario included). But there might be a cleverer option?

Comment: Change background color of li ?

Comment: There is no parent CSS selector yet. You'd need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I think It's easier just to put the classes on the LI elements rather than the span elements.

Comment: Is this what you need , check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/3a69W/6/

Comment: @j08691 I know that I need JS to do that. that's what I've been asking for. @Jop Because I need the `span` areas to be the triggers for the tabs navigation this is where the navigation script adds the classes. @Bharath Rallapalli You've just re-posted my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do a simple:

```
.tabs:hover {background-image:url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');}
```

Or a better answer: in your JS simply change:

```
tabs: s.getElements('span'),
```

to

```
tabs: s.getElements('.tabs'),
```

than add: cursor:pointer to .tabs 's css

http://jsfiddle.net/3a69W/9/

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need and what I've been asking for. The `li` cannot be the tab trigger, this is what a smaller area within needs to do, hence the `span`. What I need is to I need to style an area outside the `span` (I cannot do it with padding by the way because of how the layout will be arranged).

Answer (score 0):

See if following works:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ajays_jsfiddle/3a69W/13/][1]
```

Changes are made in all HTML, CSS and JS.